# Class with two fields: std::thread & int. Thread is supposed to increment int. Stops working as soon as a second Class Object is instantiated

Tags: c++, multithreading

lets say I have a class "Second_Counter". 
Its fields are:

```
int uptime{0};
std::thread second_counter_thread;
```

And it has the following methods:

```
Second_Counter::Second_Counter(){
    this->second_counter_thread = get_second_counter_thread(&(this->uptime));
}


std::thread Second_Counter::get_second_counter_thread(int* i){
    return std::thread (second_counter_loop, i);
}


void Second_Counter::second_counter_loop(int* i){
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        (*i)++;
    }
}


int Second_Counter::get_uptime(){
    return this->uptime;
}
```

When I create one instance of Second_Counter, everything works as expected (get_uptime() always returns a correctly incremented integer).

However, as soon as I create another instance of Second_Counter, the first Second_Counter's uptime field doesn't seem to be incremented anymore (get_uptime() always returns the value that the first Second_Counter's uptime filed had when the second one started).

Strangely, when I print out *i* inside both second_counter_loops, it seems like both loops are still running (the i's of both loops are still getting incremented)

Comment: Please include your entire `class`, not just snippets.  Also please show your actual use of the `class`.  `get_second_counter_thread` looks like a red flag.

Comment: Is `get_second_counter_thread` static?

Comment: By the way, you probably have undefined behavior since you access same `uptime` field from multiple threads without synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, and it actually hat little to do with what I thought.

I was creating the objects in question inside a loop that looked something like this:

```
while(something){


    ... obtain info_x for constructor...


    bool add {true};
    for(int i {0}; i < second_counter_list->size(); i++){
        if(second_counter_list->at(i)->get_info_x() == info_x) add = false;
    }
    if (add) {
        second_counter_list->emplace_back(info_x)); <-- I think this was the problem
    } 
}
```

(info_x is missing in my example above)

I still don't really know what has caused the problems in question,  However trial and error let me to the conclusion that this line was causing unexpected behaviour. Maybe initializing a std::thread field through an emplace_back call doesn't work for some reason?

Now, instead of using a std::vector and the loop above, I switched to using a std::vector < std::unique_ptr < Second_Counter > > and allocating on the heap like this:

```
    if (add) {
        second_counter_list->push_back(std::make_unique<Second_Counter>(info_x));
    }
```

And everything works as expected.